# How to Ensure Consistent Reference Frames for Comparing Odometer and Camera Angle Data in ROS Noetic?

Tags: ros, navigation, transforms, tf2-ros, transformation

In my ROS Noetic project of a vehicle with a camera and odometer, I'm planning to compare the vehicle's position from the odometer with the desired angle or direction detected by the camera. However, when establishing the control error, I noticed that the values from the odometer are in a different reference frame than the camera. Can you please help me understand how to ensure that when comparing the two angles (yaw and desired angle), they are in the same reference frame?

Comment: Hi! Is the vehicle a custom robot that you built from bare metal, or is it already ROS-integrated? From your post, I cannot understand if your robot has `tf` already configured, and you are asking for help on its use _or_ if it is not and you are asking for help in configuring `tf`.